# Get the value of a Promise?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs

I'm using axios to make an AJAX request to the twitchtvapi. I assigned promise to a variable called example.

Is was it is possible to get the data inside of the Promise object? If I chain the .then method to the promise object I get an error that .then is not a function.

If I log the example variable I can see that there are three promises with the values that I'm looking to store into an array similar to

```js
var example = users.map((item) => axios.get(`https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/${item}?client_id=${client_id}`)
  .then(res => {
    console.log(res.data.stream);
    return res.data.stream;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  }));
console.log(example); //an array of three Promise objects 
console.log(example.then(res => res.data)) //returns error example.then is not a function
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

TLDR; How can I get the data from a Promise object? If I try to chain the .then method I get an error that says .then is not a function.

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're calling `then` on the array that `map` returns, not on a promise. You should probably have `then` inside of the mapping function, or `map` `then` over `example`.

Comment: The variable is an array of 3 promises, if I use something like Promise.all() to make it all one promise. I can use the then method but the result I get is another promise

Comment: `Promise.all(example).then(results => console.log(results));`

Comment: Thank you Felix and Carcigenicate I seem to forget that you can only get the value of a promise inside of the then method as it will always return a promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code

```
users.map((item) => axios.get(`https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/${item}?client_id=${client_id}`)
```

returns an array of promises. An array by itself is not a promise. If you wish to execute some code after all the promises have been resolved, you can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

```
Promise.all(users.map(...))
  .then((responses) => {
    // deal with responses[0].data
    //           responses[1].data
    // etc.
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // deal with error that occurred
  });
```